# How to split Python string using regular expression

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

I would like to split a string e.g.:

```
'JEBY VB /21/01 RG SPORT LTD 3802381001 - 21/01 COM BB3434345566778'
```

with a regular expression and need output:

```
['JEBY VB', 'RG SPORT LTD', 'COM BB']
```

Comment: The problem is that I am not much familiar with regular expression so, don't have an idea, which kind of regular expression have to write to get result.

Comment: Then please find yourself a regex tutorial ([Python has one](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)) and start learning. As it stands, it's not even clear what your rules for splitting are (just two or more non-letter characters in a row?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex that negates all letters and a space, something like:

```
re.split(r'(?i)\s*[^a-z ]+\s*', 'JEBY VB /21/01 RG SPORT LTD 3802381001 - 21/01 COM BB3434345566778')
```

But you will have to omit empty chunks if any.